# For the model in the pandas dataset, is it okay to use the target column when adding a new feature?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning

For the model in the pandas dataset, is it okay to use the target column when adding a new feature?
How does it affect the model ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the general rule is you should not utilize the data which will not be available in testing or real-application. It will probably result in overfitting.